# Can modify Quickblox android sdk?

Tags: android, quickblox

I need to add some extra functionalities to existing quickblox android sdk. Is quickblox android sdk is open source project.

If it is a opensource project where is the place to download it.

If it is not a opensource project, please tell me how can I implement webrtc-video chat application from scratch.

Comment: You can do some research,program and if you run into any trouble you can post it here

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [GitHUB](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk) for quickblox.

Also, Quickblox is free as a starter edition. Please check [here](https://quickblox.com/plans/).

> Update

[Video chat using AIR](http://coenraets.org/blog/2010/07/video-chat-for-android-in-30-lines-of-code/)

[Building a WebRTC Video and Voice Chat Application](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2014-10-21-building-a-webrtc-video-and-voice-chat-application/)

[Web RTC video app tutorial](http://realtimeweekly.co/android-webrtc-tutorial-pubnub/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but first link only contain .jar files of the quickblox library. I need to get the source of the libraries.

Comment: You cannot! It is not Open Source. You need to sign up, and you will get access to the SDK and the Api's that come with it.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any idea about how can I implement web-rtc video chat application without any third party library on android platform.

Comment: You don't need to pay anything to use quickblox, you just need to register to get access to the API. Follow this: http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-android

Comment: I already implement a video-chat application by using quickblox. But I need extra functionalities which not come with quickblox. That is why I'm trying to implement the application without any third party library. I know how can I implement a web-rtc video chat application for web site, but I can't find a way it for the android. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: I've posted some links in the answer. Please check there.